# Solr grouping ignore duplicate fields

Tags: solr, solrj

I am attempting to group records in Solr 7.7 and around 85% of the fields of records in each group will be identical. Is there a way for me to return fields that are the same for each record in a group only once (per group)?

For example, I have records with fields A B C D and E. I am grouping by field A. Each record that has the same field A will have the same B C and D fields, but will have different E fields. Is there a way to return B C and D only once for each group, and return E for every record (since it is unique)?

Comment: Please post an example of the data structure and the solutions you already tried so that we can answer more easily.

Comment: Depending on what you need the document structure for, `facet.pivot` might be an option.

Comment: You should probably give an example of the query you are using, the results you are getting and an example of the results you would prefer to have instead.